# Загрузка фото из url на сервер вконтакте

Tags: python, вконтакте

Мне нужно загрузить картинку с URL на сервер вконтакте, не скачивая её. Мой код:

```
import requests

urlSrc='URL'
gid = 12345678

urlUpload = getWallUploadServer(gid)
photo = requests.get(urlSrc).content

r = requests.post(urlUpload, files={'photo': photo})
```

Если мы посмотрим что вернул сервер, то увидим, что он не получил картинку:

```
`{'server': 123456, 'photo': '[]', 'hash': 'XXX'}`
```

Я пробывал загрузить картинку из файла, заменив `photo = requests.get(urlSrc).content` на `photo = open('test.jpg', "rb")`, и никаких ошибок не было

Comment: ВК требует обязательно указать имя загружаемого файла. Через `open` оно автоматически передаётся и всё работает, а через `content` имени нет и ничего не работает

Comment: @andreymal Как мне добавить имя файла к содержанию файла?

Comment: Что-то вроде `files={'photo': ('photo.jpg', photo)}` если правильно помню